# Set cell corner radius in NSTableview

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

Is there a way to get rounded corners (and preferably shadows) on cells in `NSTableView`?  I found a way to get rounded corners on the `NSScrollView`

```
 scrollView.wantsLayer = true
 scrollView.layer?.cornerRadius = 20
```

But I could not get it working on the actual cell.

EDIT.

```
func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
    return names.count
}
    
func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
    return names[row]
}
```

I have 3 labels in the cell, each one is using `Bind To` -> `Table Cell View` And in In `Model Key Path` I have `objectValue.theValueIWantToDisplay`

Comment: what kind of cells are you using?  `NSView` (aka `NSTableCellView`) or `NSCell`?

Comment: NSTableCellView

Comment: Could you edit your question to show some more detail on how you create (or fetch) your `NSTableCellView` into your table?

Comment: I have edited the question. Does that clear things up? I'm very new to this, so bear with me

Comment: no worries!  There's a couple types of answers you can get to this question so I wanted to get things focused before I take a stab at it (and I know others are looking at this question as well).

Comment: I don't believe `objectValueFor tableColumn` will give you what you ultimately want here, especially if you are using the default `NSTableViewCell`. To get closer to what you need to do, I think you'll need to create and use your own custom `NSTableCellView` and then return that custom view via `func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? `, like what you'll see in [this RayWenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/830-macos-nstableview-tutorial#toc-anchor-007).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a view-based `NSTableView` rendering of the table view row and table view cell (these are different, where the former is a parent of the latter) is entirely up to a view. Just subclass them as any other view and use its many customization points.

Without subclassing you should be able to use `-[NSView setWantsLayer:]` and then `-[NSView layer]`, `-[CALayer setCornerRadius:]` and `-[NSView setShadow:]` to achieve the desired effect. To customize, implement `-[NSTableViewDelegate tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:]` and/or `-[NSTableViewDelegate tableView:rowViewForRow:]`.

Comment: Shouldn't "the table view row and table view cell" be "the table row view and table cell view"? It is `NSTableRowView` and `NSTableCellView`.

Comment: Yup, I always confuse the order :)